# How to detect delete listview item event on ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

How to detect delete listview item event on ListFragment?
... and then Toast.maketext......

I'm deleting items via delete item in ArrayList, and then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Update question:
I'm find it:

class MyObserver extends DataSetObserver
        {

```
            @Override
            public void onChanged()
            {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    super.onChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ch... obs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
```

Then in main code

ArrayAdapter adapter;
.....
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new MyObserver());
....

Comment: Hey Andreyua, please be more specific and add what you have already done.

Comment: After deleting, adding or changing listitem in listview(ListFragment) I'm want to make Toast...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are deleting the items.

If you are deleting items using an onClick (I'm just guessing here) than you can toast at that stage.

Alternatively if you just need to know something has been deleted you can store a variable of the size of the arrayList and then compare it to the current size of the array list. At this stage you know something has been deleted.

Could you give more information as to the scenario?